# How to align Big Icon at the center, inside smaller row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve the following layout:

[image]

Following is my code:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Icon(
      Icons.fast_rewind,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      width: 20,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.pause_circle_filled,
      size: 60,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      width: 20,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.fast_forward,
    ),
  ],
),
```

With that, this is what I get:

[image]

I thought crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center would take care of centering the Pause button. But it isn't. If I remove the pause button's size of 60, then it works fine. However, I want this button to be bigger.

How can I achieve the desired layout?

Comment: Instead of using row you can try to use Stack Widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack widget might help you. It locate widget according to Z axis

A sample to give an idea:

```
 Stack(children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.fast_rewind,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.fast_forward,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.pause_circle_filled,
                size: 60,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
  ),
```

Comment: This is good. Thanks. But I still wonder why Row isn't centering the children in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late but it will be helpful for you or someone

Just Wrap your Icon widget with SizedBox widget

Sample Code:

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: rewind10Seconds,
              icon: Icon(Icons.replay_10, size: 35),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (widget._controller.value.isPlaying) {
                    widget._controller.pause();
                  } else {
                    widget._controller.play();
                  }
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(
                widget._controller.value.isPlaying
                    ? Icons.pause_circle_filled
                    : Icons.play_circle_fill,
                size: 70,
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: forward10Seconds,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.forward_10,
                size: 35,
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Sample Output:

[image]

Comment: your output is better than the one in the question but it's still not aligned